# Help with rails link_to and post methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, methods

I need help assigning students to batches.. they are in a many to many relation.

```
        <tbody>
            <% Batch.all.each do |b|%>
            <tr>
                <td><%= b.course.name%></td>
                <td><%= b.name %></td>
                <td><%= b.section_name%></td>
                <td><%= link_to "Add", student_batch_students_path(@student, :batch_id=> b.id), :method=> :post%></td>
            </tr>
            <%end%>


        </tbody>
```

In my controller

```
def create
    @batch_student = BatchStudent.new(params[:batch_student])
    @batch_student.save    
  end
```

My routes

```
  resources :students do
    resources :batch_students
  end

resources :batches
```

But on my database it creates it with student_id and batch_id as null

Comment: I have added more details to the original post

Comment: Show your `student_batch` action and your routes

Comment: Then why is it creating the BatchStudent record?? (but with null values)

Comment: Because your question was unclear

Comment: No, your link is correct, it should route to create with :method => :post.  What does the params hash contain?  (your log/console should say)

Comment: it actually doesnt have a BatchStudent at all. it just contains batch_id and student_id, along with an authenticity_token and method ... with the correct values.. but Im guessing they should both be inside a BatchStudent hash.

Comment: One of the problems is that the generated links contain the batch_id as a url parameter... since this should make a post request to the server I was assuming this wouldnt be in the url

Comment: Nested routes do that, and the id in the url gets extracted and put into the hash for you.  Unless it bothers you, there isn't anything particularity wrong with it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are updating exist batch, but not creating, so you should make `PUT` request to `update` action

```
<td><%= link_to "Add", student_batch_students_path(@student, :batch_id => b.id), :method=> :post %></td>


def create
  @student = Student.find(params[:id])
  @batch   = Batch.find(params[:batch_id])
  @batch_student = BatchStudent.new(:params[:batch_student])
  @batch_student.student = @student
  @batch_student.batch = @batch
  @batch_student.save
end
```

Comment: That's not the case at all... I want to CREATE a BatchStudent... (which is essentially assigning a new batch to the student in question)

Comment: in your link there is `student_batch_students_path(@student, :batch_id=> b.id)` which means that you have got `b` object. Or you're totally missed

Comment: Of course I have b object... as you can see this is inside a table which is firstly displaying all the batches and its also showing the link_to assign the batch to the student

Comment: Oh. You have got `Batch`, `Student` and `StudentBatch` models :D

Comment: Ok, this isnt exactly what I ended up doing but it works. so i will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

The params hash doesn't contain a `:batch_student` hash because you are not submitting from a form.  The params has should look something like `{"student_id" => 1, "batch_id" => 1, "method" => "post"}`.

So, modify your create action as follows:

```
def create
  @batch_student = BatchStudent.new(params)
  @batch_student.save    
end

# or, a shorter version
def create
  @batch_student = BatchStudent.create(params)
end
```

The advantage of using new is you can do a `if @batch_student.save` to check for errors.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It makes sense.. the problem is that it's also sending method and authenticity token... so I get a unknown attribute "method: error

Comment: @ignaciofuentes use `params.permit(:student_id, :batch_id)` to avaoid that.

Answer (score -1):

The parameters and the http method should be together `{:batch_id=> b.id, :method=> :post}`

```
<%= link_to "Add", student_batch_students_path(@student), {:batch_id=> b.id, :method=> :post} %>
```